# How to set Frame Name of new browser when handling OnBeforePopUp in CEFSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am having issues with a particular site working in my custom CEFSharp browser which I have written in WinForms.  As far as I can tell, they are opening a URL with the javascript "window.open" method and giving the new window a specific name.  I believe the issue is that my implementation of pop up windows does not allow them to keep this reference to the new window.

I have implemented an ILifeSpanHandler and am handing the OnBeforePopup method.  I can see that their name is coming through via the "targetFrameName" parameter but I do not know how to assign it to the new IWebBrowser that I am creating.  Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
public class LifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
{
    MainForm mainForm;

    public LifeSpanHandler(MainForm form)
    {
        mainForm = form;
    }

    public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {            
        newBrowser = mainForm.AddNewBrowserTab(targetUrl);
        //how to add the targetFrameName parameter to this newBrowser?
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling CEF to not make a new window, then taking the URL and loading it in another browser instance you're creating manually.  What you need to do is route the new browser instance being created by CEF to a host control in your TabControl.

```
        newBrowser = null;

        var control = mainForm.AddNewBrowserTab(targetUrl);

        var rect = control.ClientRectangle;
        control.Invoke(new Action(() => windowInfo.SetAsChild(control.Handle, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Bottom)));

        return false;
```

Very important to return false to let CEF create the window.

```
    public Control AddNewTab2()
    {
        Control hostControl = new Control { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        tab.Controls.Add(hostControl);

        this.tabControl1.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab); }));

        return hostControl;
    }
```